# Making the Facebook Like button <fb:like /> bigger on a mobile screen

Tags: html, facebook

I have a site optimized for Mobile (240x320). All the text on it is perfectly readable except the Facebook like button which is incredibly small. Is there anyway to make this bigger?

Answer (score 1):

You can try making it bigger using CSS tranforms, like applying

```
transform: scale(2);
```

to the iframe element.

(I tried this for desktop browsers once, and it looked pretty ugly … but *maybe* it’s different on mobile.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can control the size of the button itself. You might try tweaking your options, like removing the "show faces" if you have that set, or setting the width of the containing iframe lower so that it sizes better. If that doesn't work, you should explore tweaking the rest of your content because my bet is that the "scale" of your document is off.

Comment: I am using the XFBML version of the like button <fb:like />. I do not set any px related widths in the html, yet I know that the facebook like button would. I am using WP7, so maybe it is the browser causing the issue. But I am unsure of how to scale anything, even if I set the rest of the page to really small writing hoping it will scale it out, I just end up with an unreadable page.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I misread your title and missed the XFBML part. In that case you could try an iframe? Other than that though, I'm out of ideas, except opening a bug/feature request at http://bug.developers.facebook.net. Facebook development can be maddeningly frustrating sometimes.